# Convert a Pojo list to nested lists

Tags: java, collections

I have 3 entities : Country, State, City
I have written their POJOs as :

```
class Country{
String countryName;
List<State> states;
}

class State{
String stateName;
List<City> cities;
}

class City{
String cityName;
}
```

My database table is as below :

```
Goegraphy
---------
countryName | stateName | cityName
```

Now, for fetching data from database, I made another POJO :

```
class Geography{
String countryName;
String stateName;
String cityName;
}
```

I have a List of Geography objects.
But my requirement is to convert this list into the earlier Country-State-City model now. Can someone please help how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the [One to Many](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany) association of relation databases. All `JPA` implementations can do it nicely for you, without the need of implementing your Geography Pojo.

But if you are stuck to do it manually, here is a not very optimized way of doing it with java 8 streams

```
class Country {

    public Country(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
        this.states = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    String countryName;
    List<State> states;

}

class State {

    public State(String stateName) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
        this.cities = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    String stateName;
    List<City> cities;
}

class City {
    public City(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    String cityName;
}

class Geography {
    String countryName;
    String stateName;
    String cityName;
}


List<Country> buildFromGeographies(List<Geography> geos) {

    List<Country> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Geography geo : geos) {
        Optional<Country> country1 = result.stream().filter(country -> country.countryName.equals(geo.countryName)).findFirst();
        Country country = country1.orElseGet(() -> {
            Country newOne = new Country(geo.countryName);
            result.add(newOne);
            return newOne;
        });

        Optional<State> state1 = country.states.stream().filter(state -> state.stateName.equals(geo.stateName)).findFirst();
        State state = state1.orElseGet(() -> {
            State newOne = new State(geo.stateName);
            country.states.add(newOne);
            return newOne;
        });

        // taking for granted there is no duplicates in your data set
        state.cities.add(new City(geo.cityName));
    }

    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly you have List from table and you want it to map on you POJO classes. But the problem is that you have duplicated values in table if I understand it correctly. I think you have this data in table
1. USA, Florida, Miami
2. USA, Florida, Sarasota

The Problem will be with dupplication in table. I think you should split each column in separate table and join via foreing key and it will be better. Than you can create select and join to another table and result add to your list. Now you need to create loop.

---

Comment: I have not provided detailed database description but yes, Country/State/City already are separate tables and Geography table holds the foreign keys of those tables. In Geography actually, the columns are GeographyID, CountryID, StateID and CityID.
But the main concern is of converting the Geography pojo to Country pojo.